# Concatenação com Virgula e Sinal de mais

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou estudando nodejs, e fazendo alguns testes com alguns modulos nativos do node me deparei com a seguinte instrução.

Para impressão da memoria livre no computador:

```
const os = require('os');

console.log('Memoria Livre: ', os.freemem());
```

Esta virgula separando a string da constante é de concatenação, correto?

Se sim, qual a diferença entre usar virgula e/ou +

```
console.log('Memoria Livre: ', os.freemem());
```

e/ou

```
console.log('Memoria Livre: ' + os.freemem());
```

Existem mais outros meios de concatenação em js?

Comment: você também pode usar o += que soma a variavel + ela mesma mais o outro valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é concatenação, a função `log(...)` é de múltiplos argumentos.

Quando você faz `console.log('Memoria Livre: ' + os.freemem());` você esta chamando a função com 1 argumento, que é uma string `'Memoria Livre: ' + os.freemem()` já em `console.log('Memoria Livre: ', os.freemem());` você está passando 2 argumentos para a função `log(...)`.

Isso não é do node.

> console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
>
> console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]);

```js
console.log('a', 'b', 'c');
console.log('a'+'b'+'c');

let teste = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

console.log('a'+teste);

console.log('a', teste);
```

Comment: Verdade, agora que prestei atenção. Obrigado. Brizei legal agora rs